# SQL: How to have a row even if the SELECT CASE doesn't get triggered?

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements, case

I have the following SELECT ...

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN cola < 0 THEN '-'
                WHEN cola > 0 THEN '+'
                ELSE '='
           END
           SUM(colb), SUM(colc), SUM(cold),
           MAX(CASE WHEN cola < 0 THEN 1
                    WHEN cola > 0 THEN 3
                    ELSE 2
              ) AS Sort
      FROM Table1
     WHERE this = that
  GROUP BY CASE WHEN cola < 0 THEN '-'
                WHEN cola > 0 THEN '+'
                ELSE '=' END
  ORDER BY cold
```

***This is what I'm getting:***

```
cola    colb   colc   cold
-        1       2     1
+        13      0     3
```

***This is what I'm wanting:***

```
cola    colb   colc   cold
-        1       2     1
=        0       0     2
+        13      0     3
```

When I get a result set I have '+' and '-' rows but no '=' row because there weren't any '0' values to trigger the ELSE.  How can I have it set so that if this is the case then it would still have a '=' row in my SELECT statement?

Thanks! *If more of the select is required just let me know.

Comment: You need to provide some more of the SQL statement.  It isn't clear whether you need an outer join or something else.

Comment: It sounds like you want the 0 to be represented, even though the that value wasn't in the `cola` column. Is this correct? Can you include sample before and after resultsets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
       foo.symbol,
       SUM(colb), SUM(colc), SUM(cold)
  FROM
        (SELECT '-' AS Symbol, 1 As Sort 
         UNION ALL SELECT '=', 2
         UNION ALL SELECT '+', 3
        ) foo
        LEFT JOIN
        Table1 ON foo.symbol = CASE WHEN cola < 0 THEN '-'
            WHEN cola > 0 THEN '+'
            ELSE '='
       END
 WHERE this = that
GROUP BY foo.symbol, foo.sort
ORDER BY foo.sort
```

You may need a derived table for Table1 too to apply the filter correctly. You can push th CASE into this

Edit, after comments, even simpler thanks to @WReach

```
SELECT
       foo.SignAndSort,
       SUM(colb), SUM(colc), SUM(cold)
  FROM
        (SELECT '-1' AS SignAndSort
         UNION ALL SELECT '0'
         UNION ALL SELECT '-1'
        ) foo
        LEFT JOIN
        Table1 ON foo.SignAndSort = SIGN(cola)
 WHERE this = that
GROUP BY foo.SignAndSort
ORDER BY foo.SignAndSort
```

Comment: +1 If you add a column to `foo` that gives the desired sign for each symbol, then the `CASE` expression could be simplified to `foo."sign" = sign(cola)`.

Comment: @WReach: good point. I use SIGN quite often: it's a useful yet overlooked function

Comment: Nice solution gbn. +1 Very tight! I've gotta remember that you can use a CASE in the join's `ON` clause.

Comment: It seems to be doing the same as mine as far as not displaying the "=" sign... I'm still just getting the two rows when I'm trying to get three. There is no data to trigger the "ELSE '='" in the LEFT JOIN CASE still. Unless I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: @daveomcd: remove the WHERE filter to test, but add it to the JOIN condition or as a derived table. A WHERE on the outer table changes the outer to an inner join

Comment: @gbn: thanks! moving my WHERE clause to the JOIN did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the 0 to be represented, even though the that value wasn't in the `cola` column.

My first approach would be to:

- gather the summation in a derived table (`t`)
- UNION that against another derived table with a single row containing your equals row. (`t2`)
- SELECT the MAX, which would filter out the duplicates when the `UNION ALL` produces a duplicate in the case that the equals actually existed in table `t`.

```
SELECT  MySymbol, MAX(MySumB) AS MySumB, 
                  MAX(MySumC) AS MySumC, 
                  MAX(MySumD) AS MySumD
FROM (    
        SELECT MySymbol,MySumB,MySumC,MySumD
        FROM (
                SELECT CASE WHEN cola < 0 THEN '-'
                        WHEN cola > 0 THEN '+'
                        ELSE '='
                   END  AS MySymbol,
                   SUM(colb) AS MySumB, SUM(colc) AS MySumC, SUM(cold) AS MySumD,
                   MAX(CASE WHEN cola < 0 THEN 1
                            WHEN cola > 0 THEN 3
                            ELSE 2
                      ) AS Sort
                 FROM Table1
                 WHERE this = that
                 GROUP BY CASE WHEN cola < 0 THEN '-'
                            WHEN cola > 0 THEN '+'
                            ELSE '=' END                
            UNION  ALL
            SELECT '=' AS MySymbol, 0,0,0,0
        )  t
) t2
GROUP BY MySymbol
ORDER BY MySumD
```

This could've been a bit tighter a solution if we knew the RDBMS you were using. The above is ANSI-compliant, so it'll work anywhere. A less-verbose solution likely exists for Oracle, SQL Server or MySQL, using temp tables or table variables. Since the RDBMS wasn't specified, I couldn't give a platform specific answer, and went with the generic approach.